# Geometry nodes 3.0 random array stack

Tags: modifiers, geometry-nodes

I am trying to create a random stack of meshes from a collection in geometry nodes.

Already I have an array that can detect the height of the first object but not on different objects with different heights. Is it possible to get the max height of every object and then stack them accordingly?

here is my blend file:
https://we.tl/t-unOsDy2LP2

Here is an image of what I have:
[image]

Comment: please paste pictures directly in your question. And instead of the node tree...please provide blend file. thanks.

Comment: Ah i didn't know i could do that. :) thanks. I will add the blend file as well.

Comment: This gets quite close (only for a collection of two, but if this could be made to work should be easy to expand to more): https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7Xel.png. The thing that's missing is a "cumulative sum" for the offsets, so that the next instance knows which ones got randomly selected before it..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE**

With the new accumulate field node, you can use this node setup:

[image]

result:

[image]

---

My solution isn't for sure the best and it should be a lot easier with animation nodes (which has loops) but you wanted a solution in geometry nodes. So i made a nodegroup, which basically adds one vertex to the geometry, calculates its own height with the bounding box node and outputs its next starting point. But i am sure some geniuses here will present a better solution ;) but i hope you can learn a bit from my setup.

Here is the node tree:

[image]

[image]

result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris, this helps a bunch. Maibe there is a way to generate node groups to extend the array.

Comment: I'm trying to adapt this solution and think I'm getting close. Instead of outputting the distance to use as an offset for the next node in a chain, using that distance with a Sample Curve node to instance everything on a single curve. I've got it working with a single object input (based on its bounding box). The trick I'm stuck on is getting the distinct bounding boxes for each object in the collection (I'm starting to feel that part isn't possible yet)

Comment: I also have a feeling that it can't be done jet. I did make it work in unreal engine blueprints with forloops but blender works a bit differt in that regard i guess. Maibe it was possible with attributes form 2.9. I think Chris's solution is quite ingenious in joining the stack geometry and adding another instance and then joining agian.

Comment: Wow thanks for the update, this is very helpful.

Comment: I tried to figure out how to make it work with a collection of objects and accumulate the bounding box Z dimensions but it doesnt work. Any ideas? @Chris

Answer (score 3):

Thanks, this is what i wanted to do.
I managed to do it with a sequence of your nodegroups and a couple of switches and a multigate.
Also I made seperate collections for the top, bottom and middle elements of the stacks.
basically you can put up to 8 middle instances into this system now and it will detect the heights. You could now collapse all middle nodes into another nodegroup and generate more instances exponentially.
Thanks a lot for your help.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]